Помощь в проблеме с компьютером
Сразу уточню, в курсе, что данный форум посвящён программированию, но мне посоветовали для начала обратиться сюда с моей проблемой, если данная ветка форума не соответствует теме самого форума, просьба написать, где можно обсудить мою проблему

Начну с того, что я не знаток устройства пк, знаю поверхностную информацию, без углубленных знаний в сборке и работе самого пк.
Т.К. Появились деньги на хороший компьютер, я попросил знакомого помочь с подбором комплектующих и сборкой, под его "управлением" был собран мой пк, он говорил, что куда вставлять, я делал то, что он озвучивал.
Все прошло хорошо, никаких проблем при первом запуске не возникло, накатили виду и я пошёл погружатся в мир ААА-Гейминга.
Через 2 недели использования пк, решил запустить пк после работы, и первый раз столкнулся с непонятной для меня проблемой, сам пк включился, корпус и видеокарта засветились, а вот башня на процессоре и мониторы с клава - мышь не работали.
В судорожно непонимании стал перезагружать пк, не помогло, отключил питание, воткнул шнур заново, не помогло. Где-то через минуту таких махинаций "башня включилась" и с ней монитор и Клава мышь тоже.
Я списал все на скачок электроэнергии, что как я сейчас понимаю, не является причиной такого странного запуска.
И вот прошёл месяц, я с периодичностью запускал свой пк, старт проходил быстро, башня запускалась вместе с системой и вчера опять, таже проблема что и месяц назад, все запустилось, а башня, монитор и Клава- мышь, нет.
В этот раз я решил подождать пару минут, и о чудо, башня включилась, а с ней и монитор с клавиатурой и мышью.
Причём, за время "запуска" башня работала, винты крутились, но дисплей не работал и не выводилось изображение на монитор.
Сейчас все работает и включается сразу, но, скорее всего описанная выше ситуация с не включением башни и последующим ожидании её включения, повторится внов.
Хотелось бы знать причину такой неисправности, все же это не совсем правильная работа пк.
Здесь я напишу комплектующие установленные в моей сборке:
Gigabyte Видеокарта GeForce RTX 4080 SUPER GAMING OC 16 ГБ (GV-N408SGAMING OC-16GD)
Материнская плата GIGABYTE B650M AORUS ELITE AX
Центральный процессор AMD RYZEN 5 7500F OEM (100-000000597)
Кулер для процессора DeepCool AK620 DIGITAL
Блок питания be quiet! STRAIGHT POWER 12, 1000W, 80+ Platinum, ATX3.0 (BN338)
Kingston 2 ТБ Внутренний SSD-диск KC3000 M.2 PCI-E 4.0 (SKC3000D/2048G)
Kingston 1 ТБ Внутренний SSD-диск NV2 M.2 PCI-E 4.0 (SNV2S/1000G)
Корпус Cougar Airface Pro RGB, черный
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, или направить туда, где помогут, буду благодарен

Обратитесь в сервисный центр. По этой информации удаленно ничего определить практически невозможно.

А что такое "башня на процессоре"?

@insolor можно по опыту наванговать. Сталкваюсь с сотней компов по работе - два раза в год встречается такая проблема.

Кажется, этот вопрос был написан с целью похвастаться компьютером xD

Ну так навскидку либо БП либо материнка. Либо и правда какие-то кабели дефектные )

таже проблема что и месяц назад день в день? минута в минуту? если да и пользуешься ПК без ИБП, можно конечно сослаться на профу у электриков, но... все запустилось, а башня, монитор и Клава- мышь, нет ... Причём, за время "запуска" башня работала, винты крутились, но ДИСПЛЕЙ не работал и не выводилось изображение на МОНИТОР эм... башня со своим собственным дисплеем для мониторинга температуры\нагрузки? судя по выдаче озона, как раз оно. покопайся в макросах/дровах/меню этой гхм... башни на предмет поиска автообновлений. во дожили, радиатор не хочет работать без обновлений...

ruSO - это НЕ ФОРУМ!

По моему опыту: скорее всего плохой блок питания.
Компьютер на старте потребляет больший ток чем может выдать БП. Получается просадка по напряжению и не отрабатывает сигнал старта процессора или памяти.
Рекомендую ставить блоки питания 80PLUS достаточной мощности в компьютеры для игр.

Там 1000W, 80+, какой же там нужно тогда?

исправный нужен =)

Ну это да. Я тоже склоняюсь к версии неисправности БП )

Лучше задай этот вопрос на qna.habr.com, там более широкий набор тем можно обсуждать. В сервис-центр нести не надо. Обуют так, что выйдет в стоимость нового ПК, особенно эти "мастер, живу рядом, приеду быстро, диагностика бесплатно". А так, первым делом я бы попробовал переподключить все провода от блока питания например. Ну или как минимум те, которые питают кулер ("башня над процессором").
